# Uploading large SQL Dump to a NoSQL table store

Tags: mysql, nosql, alibaba-cloud

I have a WordPress blog on an Apache server with database in MySQL, I can get a SQL dump of the database which is around 4GB in size how do I properly import that data into a NoSQL table store from Alibaba Cloud

Answer (score 0):

Besides the obvious question: Why would you want to do this?

There are no tools per se that will do this for you automatically. You will need to hand create your own tools based upon the tables, column types, etc.

You will probably find that your NoSQL database will be much larger than the traditional RDS (SQL) database that you copied from. The data layout and structure do not make for a clean "copy and paste" to NoSQL. RDS makes heavy use of references to other tables that do not easily move to NoSQL. NoSQL uses a document type of structure.

If your goal is to use a NoSQL database to replace MySQL, this is not practical today. You would need to modify WordPress. After these extensive changes you would not be able to automatically update WordPress with new updates or releases.

One area that might make sense is extracting the blog post (articles) and putting those into NoSQL.

Comment: I would like to develop a NodeJS based app and want to use a NoSQL database only for the blog post content that can be served by an API I am trying to make. So I think it will be better to only extract the blog post article using some tool. Do you have any suggestions? Or should I be writing such a program myself. Thanks.

Comment: I am not aware of any tools. Writing a program to extract blog posts from a MySQL database is very easy. The table structures are well defined for WordPress. Review the WordPress documentation, write a few test SELECT statements and you will quickly figure this out.